# Identifier expected error when calling a method in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, return, identifier

I have this rather simple code written in `java`. This is actually from a DAQ framework, called [Kmax](http://www.sparrowcorp.com/products/software)

```
import kmax.ext.*; 

public class Runtime implements KmaxRuntime {
    KmaxToolsheet tlsh; // Store a reference to the toolsheet environment
    KmaxHist hist1D;
    KmaxWidget checkBoxWidget;

    public void init(KmaxToolsheet toolsheet) {
        tlsh = toolsheet; // Save this reference for use in the toolsheet
        hist1D = tlsh.getKmaxHist("HIST1D");
        checkBoxWidget = tlsh.getKmaxWidget("CHECK_BOX_CALIB_METH");
        tlsh.getKmaxWidget("CHECK_BOX_CALIB_METH").setProperty("VALUE", "1");

    }

    public void CalibInit(KmaxWidget widget, KmaxHist histo){
        histo.setUseXAxisCalibration(stringToBool(widget.getProperty("VALUE")));
        histo.update();

    }
    CalibInit(checkboxWidget,hist1D);

    public void GO(KmaxToolsheet toolsheet){}
    public void SRQ(KmaxDevice device) {}
    public void HALT(KmaxToolsheet toolsheet) {}

} // End of the Runtime object
```

Note that there I have created an object named `CHECK_BOX_CALIB_METH`. When I compile this code I get those errors messages

```
compiler msg>error: invalid method declaration; return type required
compiler msg>   CalibInit(checkboxWidget,hist1D);
compiler msg>   ^

compiler msg>error: <identifier> expected
compiler msg>CalibInit(checkboxWidget,hist1D);
compiler msg>                        ^


compiler msg>error: <identifier> expected
compiler msg>CalibInit(checkboxWidget,hist1D);
compiler msg>                               ^
```

Note that if I remove the `CalibInit` method and replace it with

```
public void CHECK_BOX_CALIB_METH(KmaxWidget widget) {

    hist1D.setUseXAxisCalibration(stringToBool(widget.getProperty("VALUE")));
    hist1D.update();

}
```

I get no compile error. The keypoint is that the method's name is the same as the object's name. The reason I created `CalibInit()` is to avoid having each method for every object of the same type, with the same functionality. Is there a way around it?

How to avoid those errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
CalibInit(checkboxWidget,hist1D);
```

that is on a line of its own is not inside any of your methods. The compiler assumes that this is a new method declaration which is probably not what you want.

Side note:
It is not recommended to have methods starting with a upper case character: "Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized." from [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Answer (score 2):

Only variables can declare out side of methods.  You can call methods only in methods and constructor (*avoiding static context here*).

```
  CalibInit(checkboxWidget,hist1D);
```

Please move that line to any method or constructor , if needed.  More specifically call where you need it.

**In short:**   `CalibInit(checkboxWidget,hist1D);`  is orphan now. make it belong to something.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call

```
CalibInit(checkboxWidget,hist1D);
```

directly in the class like you're doing. This instruction should be inside a constructor if your goal is to call it when an instance of Runtime is constructed.

BTW: methods start with a lowercase letter by convention in Java, and you shouldn't call your class Runtime: it will confuse people because a standard Runtime class already existsin the standard libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your advice! I am new to java so I'll try my best to learn it! Thank's again!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling CalibInit(checkboxWidget,hist1D) method directly in the class not in any method. Java doesn't support this.